# Problem with custom UINavigationBar for MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have customize my UINavigationBar with UINavigationBar drawRect and it is working fine until I fire up MFMailComposeViewController, which gives me a trouble as I couldn't override UIBarButton for the mail class, it create akward view like below:

[image]

While I try to prevent the `MFMailComposeViewController` and produce code below for using the default drawRect for `MFMailComposeViewController`, it even worse it create a black `UIBar`:

[image]

The Code:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {


    //Prevent Mail Controller For Customizing NavigationBar
    for (UIView* next = [self superview]; next; next = next.superview) {
        UIResponder* nextResponder = [next nextResponder];
        if ([nextResponder isKindOfClass:[MFMailComposeViewController class]]) {
            [super drawRect:rect];
            return;
        }
    }

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"titleBar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];   

}
@end
```

What I am trying to do here is to make sure `MFMailComposeViewController` having the same style of `UINavigationBar` and `UIButtonItem`. It can be either way:

1) Both `UINavigationBar` and `UIButtonItem` have customized background

2) Default `UINavigationBar` style (gradient blue)

Would like to know can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hacking and testing, still not manage to customize the button. But this is the closest I can get, by setting the tint color of mail controller.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
mailController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];
```

Comment: Does the save and cancel buttons are enabled? In my application also I have a custom navigationbar, when I try to compose mail using MFMailComposeViewController the navigation bar of MFMailComposeViewController is overridden by custom navigationbar. So the cancel and save buttons are disabled. How to make them enable? Dose anyone have any idea?

Comment: I use subclass of UINavigationBar, when show mail compose, navigation bar buttons are disabled too. Does anyone have solution?